# Check which user exported an Oracle .dmp file (From User)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-backups

I want to know if there's a way to see the name of the user who exported an .DMP file. I tried opening the .DMP file with Notepad++, but I didn't see this information anywhere.

The reason of why I want the name of the user who created the .DMP file is to use this user name on the import command line utility (IMP) on the parameter "from user".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

know for sure this would not give the fromuser, it gives scripts with object owner as whatever id you are running the imp, example if you run 
imp SCOTT/TIGER@ORCL file=test.dmp indexfile=test.sql.
the output test.sql will have all object owner as SCOTT.

show=y is the better option.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/972606?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Check your Export log file if available, you can see the username there.

OR

Try import the dmp file using `full=y`,

```
imp username/password@dbname file=filename.dmp log=filename.log full=y
```

Comment: I can't use the "full=y" command, our database configuration don't allow it.

I tried to open the .DMP file, but where can I find the username in this file?

Comment: You can't see the username in .dmp file. if the log file is available, you can see the username there.

Comment: Oh right. Unfortunately I don't have the log file. So there's no way to check the user who exported it from the .DMP file?

I thought there was a way, because the IMP utility generates a error when you expecify the wrong 'from user' in the import command line.

Comment: in the future, you can embed the users name in the main name of the .dmp file. Good luck.